# What is the purpose of the choke inductor coil in this qrp radio transmitter?

Tags: inductor, radio, coil, transmitter, transceiver

After building and testing these circuits, I want to understand the purpose of the choke coil in these qrp trans(ceiver)mitter circuits.
[image]

[image]

https://www.qsl.net/py2ohh/trx/curumim/curumim.htm

I understand that an RFC blocks RF but allows DC to pass, but how is its value determined? Does it depend on the crystal’s frequency?

Also I noticed that the circuit worked fine with or without this inductor, how does its absence affect the behaviour of the circuit?

Comment: What did you use instead of the inductor?

Comment: Choke blocks RF but allows DC and audio to pass. || Chi=oke is just "very large impedance" compared to other RF component. It ideally appears as an open circuit at the RF frequencies concerned. || If you short the chok it MAY work on but at lower receiver sensitivity as you are loading the RF signal  with the audio components.

Comment: @Andyaka I used a straight piece of breadboard wire about 5cm in length (an inductance of a few nH).

Comment: It may work fine in receive mode, but does it work fine in transmit mode? Have you measured RF power delivered to a 50 ohm load (substituted for antenna)? **QRP** might actually be **QRPP** when that 5.6uH inductor is shorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The choke blocks RF but allows DC and audio to pass.
The choke value is non critical - it is just required to be a "very large impedance" compared to other RF components. It ideally appears as an open circuit at the RF frequencies concerned.

As configured the oscillator operates on TX and RX. On RX the signal is at lower power, and mixes with the incoming signal and produces the "heterodyned" AM audio.

On transmit key-down the 10k is shorted and the oscillator operates at higher power.

If you short the choke it MAY work on receive but at lower receiver sensitivity as you are loading the RF signal  with the audio components.

Answer (score 0):

The choke allows the oscillator to work. If there was no reactance then the key would short out the RF. This would stop the crystal oscillator stopping the qrp transmitter from working. Higher crystal frequencies call for lower choke inductance and lower crystal frequencies call for more inductance. The antenna also has an effect on the choke.

Comment: So does the resonant frequency of the RFC and the antenna capacitor need to be equal to the crystal frequency? Or am I making a bad assumption by using the LC resonance formula?